# IOS twitter login get request_token error

Tags: ios, authentication, oauth, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to get `request_token` from https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token. But I always got following error.

> "Failed to validate oauth signature and token"

Below is my signature_base:

```
POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3DydxYUl45Mleo5LNyoExnAF4mY%26oauth_nonce%3D9C918901-EF8A-4B84-BDF5-B7E754C46397%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1415174195%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

The auth header generated is:

```
{
    Authorization = "OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", 
    oauth_nonce=\"9C918901-EF8A-4B84-BDF5-B7E754C46397\", 
    oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", 
    oauth_consumer_key=\"ydxYUl45Mleo5LNyoExnAF4mY\", 
    oauth_timestamp=\"1415174195\", 
    oauth_callback=\"http://www.google.com\",
    oauth_signature=\"j6k3CY4Fr40SKAWiG%2B5%2BwkErdYc%3D\"";
}
```

I verified the signature with my secret key and it's correct. Really can't figure out where the problem is...

One clue is that when `oauth_callback` is not used at all, I'm able to get request token... Please help!

Thanks,
Lee

**Edit**:
If I don't use `oauth_callback`, I'm able to get request token and the callback I set in dev twitter website is used. However, I can't set it to URL Scheme of my app since it's not valid url...

Comment: show ur code what u tried

Comment: Jon Susiak pointed it out my problem and now this part is working. I'm able to get request token and secret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not encoding the oauth_callback url correctly.

In the signature base it should be encoded as:

```
oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com
```

and then in the Authorization header as:

```
oauth_callback="http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Why in the signature base. It should be %253A instead of %3A, %252F instead of %2F?

Comment: Each key-value pair is first encoded and joined to form the parameter string and then the whole parameter string is encoded and joined to the signature base string. This means that parameters get encoded twice.

Comment: You saved my day Jon! Thanks. One more question: I set the callback to be `oahil://` and set `oahil` in my `info.plist`'s `URL types -> Item 1 -> URL Schemes -> Item 0`. I would like to switch to my app after authorization. But after authorization, the page is redirected to my twitter homepage... If I didn't set `oauth_callback`, it redirects to the url I set in twitter app settings. But I can't set `oahil://` there since it's not valid url... Any idea what the problem may be?

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with ios development, but if you open another question I'm sure someone will be able to help you.

Comment: I solved it. I need to provide some path after `oahil://`. After I changed it to `oahil://signin_with_twitter`, it's working now. Really hope twitter has sdk to make life easier, like facebook... But good learning experience... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The same problem i was struggling as well.
Approach that help is bellow.

Using Twitter to authenticate is quite uncomfortable to do due to the errors and bad documentation. I will defiantly recommend you, to use  one of the two approaches that are : Github [library](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter) that is well documented and easy to implement. Or use iOS `Social` framework to write own logging.